# Unable to update PyTorch 1.4.0 to 1.5.0 using Conda

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, conda, torchvision

When I tried to udpdate PyTorch from 1.4.0 to 1.5.0, Anaconda says that all the packages are already installed.

```
$ conda install -c pytorch pytorch torchvision

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

```
$ conda list | grep -i torch

_pytorch_select           0.2                       gpu_0  
pytorch                   1.4.0           py3.7_cuda10.0.130_cudnn7.6.3_0    pytorch
torchvision               0.5.0                py37_cu100    pytorch
```

I believe 1.5.0 is available in the `pytorch` channel

```
$ conda search -c pytorch pytorch=1.5.0

Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
pytorch                        1.5.0     py3.5_cpu_0  pytorch             
pytorch                        1.5.0 py3.5_cuda10.1.243_cudnn7.6.3_0  pytorch             
pytorch                        1.5.0 py3.5_cuda10.2.89_cudnn7.6.5_0  pytorch             
pytorch                        1.5.0 py3.5_cuda9.2.148_cudnn7.6.3_0  pytorch             
pytorch                        1.5.0     py3.6_cpu_0  pytorch             
pytorch                        1.5.0 py3.6_cuda10.1.243_cudnn7.6.3_0  pytorch             
pytorch                        1.5.0 py3.6_cuda10.2.89_cudnn7.6.5_0  pytorch             
pytorch                        1.5.0 py3.6_cuda9.2.148_cudnn7.6.3_0  pytorch             
pytorch                        1.5.0     py3.7_cpu_0  pytorch             
pytorch                        1.5.0 py3.7_cuda10.1.243_cudnn7.6.3_0  pytorch             
pytorch                        1.5.0 py3.7_cuda10.2.89_cudnn7.6.5_0  pytorch             
pytorch                        1.5.0 py3.7_cuda9.2.148_cudnn7.6.3_0  pytorch             
pytorch                        1.5.0     py3.8_cpu_0  pytorch             
pytorch                        1.5.0 py3.8_cuda10.1.243_cudnn7.6.3_0  pytorch             
pytorch                        1.5.0 py3.8_cuda10.2.89_cudnn7.6.5_0  pytorch             
pytorch                        1.5.0 py3.8_cuda9.2.148_cudnn7.6.3_0  pytorch
```

Why is conda not updating PyTorch to 1.5.0?

Using Python 3.7.3 & conda 4.8.3 on Ubuntu 18.04

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Install Validates Constraints

The Conda `install` first checks to see if a constraint is satisfied, rather than blindly trying to install the latest of everything. A better reading of the command:

```
conda install -c pytorch pytorch torchvision
```

would be

> *With the **pytorch** channel prioritized, ensure that the currently activated environment has some version of `pytorch` and `torchvision` installed.*

Your environment already satisfies this constraint, so there is nothing to do.

### Updating Packages, or Constraints

If you want to update a package, then look into the `conda update` command or, if you know a minimum version you require, then specify it:

```
conda install -c pytorch pytorch[version='>=1.5'] torchvision
```

which effectively changes the constraint.

### Better Practice (Recommended)

Best practice though is to simply make a new env when you require changes to packages. Every time one changes the packages in an env, one risks breaking/invalidating existing code.

```
conda create -n pytorch_1_5 -c pytorch pytorch torchvison
```

And this will grab the latest possible versions by default.

Comment: I'm trying your constrained update approach for Pytorch 1.7.0 and I'm getting the following error: `Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.` Then it spins while saying `Solving environment: `

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer this is expected behavior. Let it run. Just be aware that changing package versions in an existing env is nearly always more involved and harder to solve than creating a new env.